# Merge two arrays which inlclude null and object element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

If I have two javascript arrays.

```
const a = [null,null,{a:1}];
const b = [{c:3},null,{a:3,b:2}];
```

I want a function which can return the following result .

```
[{c:3},null,{a:3,b:2}]
```

And the above still can apply to the following.

```
const a = [];
const b = [null,null,{t:4}];
```

I want to have the following result.

```
[null,null,{t:4}]
```

Can someone help me? Thanks !

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "merge two arrays". In your first example `{a:1}` is not in the resulting list.

Comment: Have you tried .concat()? or Spread syntax?

Comment: what? you dont like A1? you prefer a different sauce ?

Comment: uhh  does ```[...a,...b]``` not provide what you want ?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to merge those objects that have the same index in the input arrays:

```js
function merge(a, b) {
    const merged = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length || i < b.length; i++) {
        merged.push(a[i] && b[i] ? {...a[i], ...b[i]} : a[i] || b[i]);
    }
    return merged;
}

console.log(merge([null,null,{a:1}], [{c:3},null,{a:3,b:2}]));
console.log(merge([], [null,null,{t:4}]));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i want !

Answer (score 2):

You could merge the items by checking the falsy value as well.

```js
const
    merge = (...a) => a.reduce(
        (r, a) => (a.forEach((o, i) => r[i] = o || r[i] || !r[i] && o), r),
        []
    );

console.log(merge([null, null, { a: 1 }], [{ c: 3 }, null, { a: 3, b: 2 }]));
console.log(merge([], [null, null, { t: 4 }]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = [];
const b = [null,null,{t:4}];

const c = [...a, ...b];

console.log(c);
```

How about using the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator?

You can also use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method to merge two arrays like so

```js
const a = [];
const b = [null,null,{t:4}];

const c = a.concat(b);
console.log(c)
```

Comment: Additionally, you can use `const c = a.concat(b);`

Comment: `console.log(c)` in the snippet

Comment: @OnurArı I was updating my post as you commented on it :P

Comment: Did you check what this produces for the first example in the question?

Comment: @trincot Yes but it looks like a typo to me.

Answer (score 1):

Concat or Spread Operator should do it..

```js
const a1 = [];
const b1 = [null,null,{t:4}];
const result1 = [...a1, ...b1];
console.log(result1);

const a2 = [null,null,{a:1}];
const b2 = [{c:3},null,{a:3,b:2}];
const result2 = [...a2, ...b2];
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: See the expected output told by OP

Answer (score 1):

I like to split the processing into two parts:

```js
const zipWith = (fn) => (a, b) => [...Array(Math.max(a.length, b.length))]
  .map((_, i) => fn(a[i], b[i]))

const combine = zipWith ((a, b) => 
  a && b ? {...a, ...b} : a ? {...a} : b ? {...b} : null)

console.log(combine([null, null, {a: 1}], [{c: 3}, null, {a: 3, b: 2}]))
console.log(combine([], [null, null, {t: 4}]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

"`zip`" is a common name for a function which combines two arrays, index-by-index.  Sometimes "`zipWith`" is used for an extension which takes a function for deciding how to combine those two values.  This version of `zipWith` is slightly more complicated than other variations, as it uses the longer length of its two input arrays, rather than just the length of the first one (which might be written `zip = (fn) => (a1, a2) => a1.map((a, i) => fn(a, a2[i]))`.)

`combine` calls this with a function that handles the four cases : `a null` / `b null`, `a null / b non-null`, `a non-null / b null`, and `a non-null / b non-null`, using or combining the values supplied.

`zipWith` is a quite reusable function that you might find helpful elsewhere in your app.  `combine` is more specific to this case.